# phonegap ios contact read detect permission given or not

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, permissions, contacts

If a user denies the contact read permission in ios, is there any way to know that? I want to run two different function depending on whether granted or not.
For example, when you first try to read contact, ios on iPhone will ask if you want to grant the permission. I want to know that and execute a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Rinku Das,
is possible to work around this but there are two problems:

1. Is not possible in hybrid way, you must create a native plugin or change an existing one
2. Apple, probably, will reject your app.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966134/1636209) you can find a good startpoint to work on it

Comment: I am not avoiding it. I will ask for the permission and depending on choice let us suppose will notify the user what permission he/she has given. And I am not making a native app but using phonegap/cordova.

Comment: If you want develop a only hybrid/js application phonegap/cordova the answer is no, is not possible.
If you want to achieve your goal you must develop a plugin ( native code ) and add it to your phonegap application. Remember that phonegap/cordova application without plugins ( cordova API or third parties ) are only responsive websites, in this case the feature that you want is pretty native and need to have a native code development.